# Как правильно построить отношение в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется две таблицы users, check.

В одной содержатся данные результатов тестирования, в другой данные пользователей.

Таблицы имеют одинаковое уникальное поле, которые их связывает. 'uid'.

Пытаюсь вывести ТОП 15 работ. С кол-вом баллов и именем участника. Пытаюсь связать таблицы:

Модель

```
class Variant extends Model {
public $timestamps = false;

protected $table = 'check';

public $primaryKey = 'uid';

public function check() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\User','uid','uid');
}

}
```

И контроллер:

```
$infoForTable = Variant::with('check')->where('subject','inf' )->where('variant','1')->orderBy('ball2', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

Пробую сделать

```
dump($infoForTable);
```

Выводит только данные вариантов

**UPDATE**

Получилось добиться вывода данных таким образом:

Контроллер:

```
  $infoForTable = Variant::with('check')->take(3)->get();
```

Модель:

```
class Variant extends Model{
public $timestamps = false;

protected $table = 'check';

public $primaryKey = 'uid';

public function check(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','uid','uid');
}
}
```

Но теперь никак не могу добавить условие:

```
where('subject','inf' )->where('variant','1')->orderBy('ball2', 'desc')
```

Comment: Ну начнем с того, что  тут нужен belongsTo, а не hasOne все таки по логике Вариант принадлежит пользователю а не вариант имеет одиного пользователя

Comment: Ну и во вторых интересно понять где ты ищешь свои данные ? они должны лежать в relations, кстати можно пользоваться dd() для удобства

Comment: А куда ты его пытаешься добавить ?

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Делаю дамп, в #relations смотрю. Сейчас удалось добиться вывода, но только без сортировки

Comment: Добавляй условия после with, а  take и get в самом конце

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо. А если возникает ошибка Trying to get property of non-object при выводе данных, которых получается нет, в шаблон, то можно ее как-то избежать делая проверку if?
UPD. Попробовал, получилось {{ isset($data->check->avatar) ? $data->check->avatar : 'Default'}}

Comment: оберни в try ctach или проверяй на пустоту if(empty($item->check)), вообще не пойму почему ты назвал check если явно просится метод  user или owner

Comment: Уже переименовал, пытался разобраться, как работают отношения во фреймворке. Оформите, как ответ?  Отмечу, что решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Первая ошибка была в отношениях, нужен  belongsTo, а не hasOne все таки по логике Вариант принадлежит пользователю а не пользователь варианту

2) Очередность выборки была не верной, сперва with, затем условия, сортировка и уже на конечном этапе кол-во и собственно выбор.

3) Так же посоветовал бы назвать функции более говорящие (или комментировать их), что бы по прошествию времени вы могли бы вспомнить, что ж это такое, тут больше подходит owner (владелец) или просто user или ученик, смотря, какую роль несет связка в данном контексте, если это человек который проверяет то не check, а например teacher